# Como determinar se um valor string esta no formato XML?

Tags: string, xml, rest, services

Eu estou me conectando com uma API, ou serviço como queiram, que me retorna um xml quando ele encontra dados no banco de dados , mas infelizmente ele retorna uma string caso nada seja encontrado ou ocorra um erro. Na minha aplicação eu estou utilizando o seguinte código para me conectar a essa API e recuperar os dados:

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(_fileUrl);

 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

 Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

 var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

 string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

 xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseFromServer);
```

Como é de se esperar quando não há dados no banco ocorre um erro quando ao dar um load no xmlDoc porque a variável responseFromServer não é XML mas uma string.

A pergunta é: Como fazer para identificar se minha string retornou um xml ou não? EU não quero ""tentar" dar um load e se não der certo entender que o que veio foi uma string. Posso estar mascarando outros erros ao fazer isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode verificar se `response.ContentType` corresponde a `application/xml` ou `text/xml` e usar essa informação para tomar a decisão. Se o serviço estiver bem configurado, ele deve enviar esse cabeçalho (e enviar `text/plain` para a mensagem de erro).

Comment: perfeito, bem melhor do que gerar uma exceção para checar a "procedência" do retorno. Muito obrigado.